# Loop when fetching COUNT in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query_count="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table";
$result_count = mysql_query($query_count);
$final_count=mysql_fetch_array($result_count);
echo $final_count[0];
```

This cause the website to "loop" (page never loads, browser runs out of memory). any idea how to do it?

Comment: Your website "loops?" What do you mean? Does the page never load?

Comment: exactly, browser takes most of my RAM.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be :

```
$query_count="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table";
$result_count = mysql_query($query_count);
$final_count=mysql_fetch_row($result_count);
echo $final_count[0];
```

Comment: There's nothing in the original code that will 'loop', but in the original code `$final_count` would be an array and `echo $final_count` would simply print 'Array'. @Blackie123: Are you sure there aren't any infinite loops elsewhere in your script?

Comment: @Blackie123 I simply used `mysql_fetch_row` as we always expect one row, you can continue to use `mysql_fetch_array` if you want. The main difference is the last line. Chris is correct in pointing out that there is nothing in this part of the code which would cause the the page to go into an infinite loop, something else seems to be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

try replacing `echo $result_count;` with `echo $final_count;`

EDIT - another option:

```
$query_count="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table";
$result_count = mysql_query($query_count);
$final_count=mysql_fetch_field($result_count, 0);
echo $final_count;
```

Comment: that one causes the loop but how shall I find out the count other then that?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$query_count="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table";
$result_count = mysql_query($query_count);
echo mysql_result($result_count, 0, 0);
```